# Teradata CLOB object

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

How to have a **hyperlink** column in the teradata table if i select the hyper link column the it has to be redirected to that link,

How to insert record in CLOB object

Thanks
Vinoth.B

Comment: Welcome .. please refer section : How to ask question ? required your trial and error code .

Comment: On the surface, this seems to be two different questions. And hyperlink redirection is a client function, not a database operation.